# ¿por que no me muestra cual numero es mayor y menor?

Tags: c++

Me mandaron a hacer un programa donde introduzco un numero en segundos y el me lanza esos segundos convertidos en horas, minutos y segundos, esa parte esta bien hecha. Pero dentro de ese mismo programa tengo que crear uno donde ingreso cinco números y me muestre cual es el mayor y cual es el menor, con ayuda de una función, pero cuando lo ejecuto sin importar que números ponga siempre me dice que el mayor y el menor es 1.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void tiempo(int segundos){
    int hora;
    int minuto;
    hora=segundos/3600;
    segundos=segundos%3600;
    minuto=segundos/60;
    segundos=segundos%60;
    cout<<"La equivalencia es: "<<hora<<":"<<minuto<<":"<<segundos<<endl; 
}

void orden(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int mayor, int menor){
int menor(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);{
    if(a<b) b=a;
    if(a<c) c=a;
    if(a<d) d=a;
    if(a<e) e=a;
    if(b<c) c=b;
    if(b<d) d=b;
    if(b<e) e=b;
    if(c<d) d=c;
    if(c<e) e=c;
    if(d<e) e=d;
}
int mayor(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);{
    if(a>b) a=b;
    if(a>c) a=c;
    if(a>d) a=d;
    if(a>e) a=e;
    if(b>c) b=c;
    if(b>d) b=d;
    if(b>e) b=e;
    if(c>d) c=d;
    if(c>e) c=e;
    if(d>e) d=e;
}
    cout<<"el mayor es: "<<mayor<<endl;
    cout<<"el menor es: "<<menor<<endl;
}
main(){
    int totalSeg;
    cout<<"ingresa el numero de segundos: ";
    cin>>totalSeg;
    tiempo(totalSeg);
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int mayor;
    int menor;
    cout<<"ingresa un numero: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"ingresa un numero: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"ingresa un numero: ";
    cin>>c;
    cout<<"ingresa un numero: ";
    cin>>d;
    cout<<"ingresa un numero: ";
    cin>>e;
    orden(a,b,c,d,e,mayor,menor);
}
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que esto compila `int mayor(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);{`? Fíjate en `;` antes de `{`.

Comment: es que si quito el ; que esta antes de { me lanza este error  (1.cpp [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token)

Comment: Tienes toda tu estructura mal, que al quitar algo o poner algo te deje de aparecer un error no significa que esté bien

Comment: fíjate en esta parte: `void orden(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int mayor, int menor){
int menor(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);{` corrije esto y continua con tu programa :)

Comment: @NicolásPazMejia es que defines una función dentro de una función, lo cuál no está permitido.

Answer (score 0):

1. Nunca estas guardando ningún dato en las variables de mayor y menor.
2. Tenes que comparar los números con las variables mayor y menor, esto se puede hacer utilizando banderas o colocando absurdos. Es decir si vos colocas en la variable mayor (int mayor = 0) Sabes que el numero que ingrese va a ser mayor a 0. Entonces guardas el numero ingresado en esa variable y pasaría a ser el nuevo mayor. En el caso del menor lo mismo pero con un absurdo muy grande, por ejemplo 99999999.
3. Te recomiendo utilizar un ciclo for y de esa manera no tendrías que ingresar 5 variables distintas sino solo una.

El código:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void tiempo(int segundos){
    int hora;
    int minuto;
    hora=segundos/3600;
    segundos=segundos%3600;
    minuto=segundos/60;
    segundos=segundos%60;
    cout<<"La equivalencia es: "<<hora<<":"<<minuto<<":"<<segundos<<endl;
}


main(){



int num, i, mayor = 0, menor = 999999, nMayor, nMenor;

for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero: "<<endl;
    cin>>num;

    if(num > mayor){
        mayor = num;

    }

    if(num < menor){
        menor = num;
    }


}

cout<<"El numero mayor es el:"<<mayor<<endl;
cout<<"El numero menor es el: "<<menor<< endl;







return 0;
}
```

De esta manera optimizarías mucho más tu código. Por otro lado te recomiendo practicar mas, ya que tu error no es esencialmente de código sino de lógica y veo que salteas pasos. Tendrías que aprender lo que son vectores (arrays) matrices, ciclos corte de control antes que comenzar a utilizar funciones. Hay documentación por montones y por doquier y también videos explicativos. De todas maneras espero que esto te haya resuelto el problema y te ayude a futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta que los enteros pueden ser positivos y negativos, y que los valores máximo y mínimo representables en un tipo `int` dependen de la CPU/plataforma.

En el ejemplo de código que pongo aquí debajo, los límites representables por un `int` se obtienen con `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` y `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Este código te resuelve los dos problemas y, además, te muestra una manera más óptima de calcular la división entera con parte entera y resto de la división. La función `div` está en `<stdlib.h>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

void tiempo(int segundos) {
    div_t divres;
    
    divres = div(segundos, 3600);
    int hora = divres.quot;
    
    divres = div(divres.rem, 60);
    int minuto = divres.quot;
    
    divres = div(divres.rem, 60);
    int segundo = divres.rem;
    
    cout.fill('0');
    cout << segundos << " segundos son: " << setw(2) << hora << ":" << setw(2) << minuto << ":" << setw(2) << segundo << endl;
}


int mayor(int const *datos, int cantidad){
    int myr = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    
    while (cantidad > 0)
    {
        if (myr < *datos)
          myr = *datos;
          
        datos++;
        cantidad--;
    }
    return myr;
}


int menor(int const *datos, int cantidad){
    int mnr = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    
    while (cantidad > 0)
    {
        if (mnr > *datos)
          mnr = *datos;
          
        datos++;
        cantidad--;
    }
    return mnr;
}

int main()
{
    int datos[] = {2,5,1,8,9,-3,4,7};
    int cantidad_datos = sizeof(datos)/sizeof(datos[0]);
    
   tiempo(3600 + 120 + 5);
   
   cout << "Mayor = " << mayor(datos, cantidad_datos) << endl;
   cout << "Menor = " << menor(datos, cantidad_datos) << endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Este código lo puedes probar [aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php).

Si tienes cualquier duda no dudes en comentarlo. Y si crees que es una buena respuesta... ;)